# Display value from specific model/queryset once POSTED to template Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-templates

This is my code for the view

```
def return_chat(request):
    context = {'client_name': request.POST['client_name'], 'messages': [], 'datetime': []}

    def order_messages():
        replies = Replies.objects.all().filter(unique_num=request.POST['unique_num'])
        sent_messages = InstantMessages.objects.all().filter(unique_num=request.POST['unique_num']) + 'S'
        from itertools import chain
        all_messages = list(chain(replies, sent_messages))
        all_messages.sort(key=lambda x: x.datetime)
        return all_messages

    for item in order_messages():
        context['messages'].append(item.message)
        context['datetime'].append(item.datetime)
    return render(request, 'chat.html', context)
```

[image]

My HTML code:

```
    <html>
        <body>
            <div style="position:relative;background-color:#f5f5f5;width:900px;height:500px;border-radius:15px;border:2px solid black;margin:auto;margin-top:10%;">
                <div style="position:absolute;left:20px;padding:10px;top:15px;border-left-style:solid;border-left-color:#48b8fa;margin:auto;width:870px;max-height:350px;overflow-y:scroll;">
                    {% for all_messages in messages %}
                    <br>
                        {{ all_messages }}
                    <br>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
                <textarea placeholder="Type your message to {{ client_name }} here.." style="background-color:#f5f5f5;position:absolute;width:900px;height:90px;border-bottom-left-radius:15px;border-bottom-right-radius:15px;bottom:0;border:2px solid black;right:-2px;bottom:-2px;padding:20px;margin:auto;padding-right:80px"></textarea>

                <button style="position:absolute;width:80px;height:90px;border-bottom-right-radius:15px;bottom:0;border:2px solid black;right:-2px;bottom:-2px;"><b>Send</b></button>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Essentially. I want the **replies** on the left and the **InstantMessages**  to appear on the right side in the Django template. Currently, they are both displayed with no difference. I want to know how to reference them independently.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can have an identifier that distinguish message between "replies" and "instant messages". Consider you have a field called "message_type" in both models "InstantMessages" and "Replies". In both models, "message_type" definition is same and it accepts any one value from ['recieved' , 'sent'].
2. Now every object of "Replies" and "InstantMessages" models have this field "message_type". In template, depending on this field value, you can set the style so that text appears left or right.

   ```
   <div style=".......">
       {% for all_messages in messages %}
           {% if message.message_type="sent"%}
               <div style="text-align:right">{{message}}</div>
           {% else %}
               <div style="text-align:left">{message}</div>
           {% endif %}
       {% endfor %}
   </div>
   ```

Comment: Hey, I'm having trouble actually implementing this. Especially with having them sorted as well.

Comment: Do you mean that you were not able to sort messages based on DateTime? Could you please elaborate more on what's the issue and how your actual result is different from your expectation

Comment: I've had to post a new question, new roadblock :/